# Create an image from JSON file?

Tags: php, json, image, image-processing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Transform array to png in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11199723/transform-array-to-png-in-php)

Pixels.JSON

```
{
  "274:130":"000",
  "274:129":"000",
  "274:128":"000",
  "274:127":"000",
  "274:126":"000",
  "274:125":"000",
}
```

What is the best way to go from a JSON file with X, Y coordinates and hex codes to an generating an image based on the data?

Comment: Decode it, use a loop, the [image functions](http://php.net/gd), split up the hex numbers, then draw pixels or lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is missing here is `height` and `width` but if you can get then you can use [imagesetpixel](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagesetpixel.php) to generate images from pixel

Example

```
$pixels = '{
      "274:130":"000",
      "274:129":"000",
      "274:128":"000",
      "274:127":"000",
      "274:126":"000",
      "274:125":"000"
    }';

$list = json_decode($pixels, true);

//#GENERATE MORE DATA
for($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i ++) {
    $list[mt_rand(1, 300) . ":" . mt_rand(1, 300)] = random_hex_color();
}

$h = 300;
$w = 300;

$gd = imagecreatetruecolor($h, $w);
// ImageFillToBorder($gd, 0, 0, 0, 255);

foreach ( $list as $xy => $color ) {
    list($r, $g, $b) = html2rgb($color);
    list($x, $y) = explode(":", $xy);
    $color = imagecolorallocate($gd, $r, $g, $b);
    imagesetpixel($gd, $x, $y, $color);
}

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($gd);
```

Sample Output

[image]

Function Used

```
function html2rgb($color) {
    if ($color[0] == '#')
        $color = substr($color, 1);
    if (strlen($color) == 6)
        list($r, $g, $b) = array($color[0] . $color[1],$color[2] . $color[3],$color[4] . $color[5]);
    elseif (strlen($color) == 3)
        list($r, $g, $b) = array($color[0] . $color[0],$color[1] . $color[1],$color[2] . $color[2]);
    else
        return false;
    return array(hexdec($r),hexdec($g),hexdec($b));
}

function random_hex_color(){
    return sprintf("%02X%02X%02X", mt_rand(0, 255), mt_rand(0, 255), mt_rand(0, 255));
}
```

Comment: Anyway to generate image with data from Json? E.G Based on the sample data above. Generate an image that says 000.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean, in a client web page / in a browser: you can create a HTML5 canvas and draw directly on to it according to your JSON data; I imagine it would be slow but it would work.

Your 'best' option may be to reconsider why you are sending image data in a JSON object, but I guess that has some context to it that wasn't shared.